# Not getting value populated in the success callback of angular ui modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I'm trying to replicate an issue in plunker but unable to do it. I've both the code exactly same but plunker still behaves differently for some reason. My issue is that I'm not getting "personModified" populated in the original code for some reason. It does work in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/CexDMZ32KweLxGrV1TJE?p=preview

```js
 modalInstance.result.then(function(personModified) {
   modalCtrl.people.push(personModified);
   $log.info('personModified = ' + personModified.name + ' Finished at: ' + new Date());
 }, function() {
   $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
 });
 };
```

Does anyone know why this value is not populating in the callback? Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Is there in any error in console ? And if possible post your complete code.

Comment: IF plunker is working and your code is not how can i help you :-P
Post your complete code.

Comment: Do you know how is that value populated like whichever object I have on modal HTML. Is that the one that is going to populated?

Comment: No,the value you sent in  $modalInstance.close($scope.person); will be available in your main View.And it is going to catch in  modalInstance.result.then(function(personModified)

Comment: It's the same code. I know it's hard to tell unless you see the code. :( but I can't post the actual post due to confidential reasons. Do you know where is that value populated from? Like what populates that value?

Comment: OK that's what is the problem. In the plunker $scope.person is not being populated from anywhere. Do you know where that value is coming from in Plunker? I did another example of update where I was passing person as dependency in CreatePersonModalController but when I pass it in this example of create, it complains. This behavior I can replicate in Plunker if you want to take a look.

Comment: @squiroid In this plunker  http://plnkr.co/edit/w1156jLlVotPrYe9MyWB?p=preview I could pass person in ModalInstanceCtrl but when I try the same thing in http://plnkr.co/edit/rCmiiri2GaV8Miab5fKr?p=preview, the modal doesn't load. Do you know why? I think is what is the issue in my case.

Comment: @squiroid if your theory holds correct then $scope.person should not be undefined. Here is the output from this pluker http://plnkr.co/edit/4cHVyxHsgKU8kPlW7fXs?p=preview
 $scope.person-->undefined
angular.js:10126 personModified = Dewrtyu Finished at: Sat Feb 28 2015 22:21:23 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

$scope.person is undefined while modalInstance.result.then(function( is still getting the value.

Comment: obviously second one will not work.Actually resolve is sending data from your mainview to model view.In second case their is no reolve so it will not get the data in person and will give you the error of personProvider not found.

Comment: Here is the way data is going resolve ->modelView->$modalInstance.close($scope.person);->modalInstance.result.then(function(personModified) ->MainView

Comment: @squiroid and I don't have resolve for a reason as I don't have anything to resolve. But modelView should be sending data to $modalInstance.close($scope.person); which in this is not. But I'm somehow still getting data in modalInstance.result.then(fun‌​ction(personModified)

Comment: you have modal template in which you have <input type="text" data-ng-model="person.name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name of the Person" required> which is $scope.person for modal :-P

Comment: @squiroid If that is the case, why is $scope.person undefined in $modalInstance.close in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4cHVyxHsgKU8kPlW7fXs?p=preview when I print it in console. You can try setting a name and check in the console for yourself. This prints two times. First when I open the modal and second when I've set the name and closing the modal.

Comment: and both times it is undefined even when I can successfully print the value in modalInstance.result.then(fun‌​ction(personModified)

Comment: Initially person is undefined because it doen't have any value.
And its getting difficult to understand what you want in your question.
Please replicate the exact senario for better understanding :-)

Comment: @squiroid Posted as answer for your clarity. In that you can clearly see it's undefined both times.

Comment: @squiroid I take my comment back. You are right. Value is being set when I put console.log inside ok function. Let me check if that is set in my function.

Comment: hehe ok check if first :-)

Comment: @squiroid OK the value is definitely not coming inside ok in my case. But I do have data-ng-model set to business.name and I'm expecting business object in ok. I can't spot any differences. :( what else could be wrong, any leads?

Comment: You can send person object with button itself like  ng-click="ok(person)" as in 

http://plnkr.co/edit/IHk5VihzcQDZnu9Ek24z?p=preview

Comment: This seems to be working. Are there any problems doing this way? Yeah I figured this was definitely scope issue as I have multiple scope in play on my HTML. I wish if I could do "controller as" syntax on modal controller as well. :(

Comment: @squiroid There is one problem though. When I don't use resolve, I lose prototype functions from the object when object is passed to a function, say remove. In the same plunker, say I had remove function which I could use after adding and in that I pass the same person object. When I get it in my controller, I lose my proto functions such $save etc that comes from $resource. Any thoughts on this problem? This happened in my create function as well. I had to recreate my object. In  case of create, recreating was fine but in remove, it just feels odd. :( I wish there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what was your exact problem but sending object from model view to modal and than from modal to mainview resolved it and i hope you learnt the way data travelled in modal.

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok(person)">OK</button>
```

You can send person object with button itself like ng-click="ok(person)" as in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IHk5VihzcQDZnu9Ek24z?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

@squiroid If I were able to replicate the scenario, I would do it. :( I don't like these back and forth comments either. It's not undefined only first time. It's also second time. Look at these logs below.

1st time when value wasn't set.

```js
 $scope.person-->undefined
angular.js:10126 Modal dismissed at: Sat Feb 28 2015 22:20:58 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

2nd time when value was set.

```js
app.js:59 $scope.person-->undefined
angular.js:10126 personModified = Dewrtyu Finished at: Sat Feb 28 2015 22:21:23 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

Here is the plunker once again. You can run and check. http://plnkr.co/edit/4cHVyxHsgKU8kPlW7fXs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

You can send person object with button itself like ng-click="ok(person)" as in plnkr.co/edit/IHk5VihzcQDZnu9Ek24z?p=preview